# APNS Push Requests are successfully sent but passes are not updating

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I have an app set up to generate passbook passes. The successfully install on the device and I can do manual (pull-down) updates.

Next I began to implement APNS.  I'm using the enhanced request method to connect to the production environment, sending in an empty payload (as required) and it returns no error codes when I request a push notification, but my pass never updates and I see no requests hitting my server. I'm using my own device to test until I can get see an update for myself. No pass updates are received.

I then implemented the Feedback service in the hope that it might tell me something.  I noticed this.  If I pass in the push token, I receive a response which indicates that the device is not receiving notifications (even though the pass is set for automatic updates).  The pass is not updated.

I'd appreciate any info into why the the push notifications do not seem to be arriving.

Thanks.
-Erich

Answer (score 2):

One gotcha to check is that you are not using the sandbox APNS server.  All Passbook push requests should be sent to the live APNS server.

Try enabling the additional logging option from the PassKit section of the Developer Settings on your device then connecting your device to Xcode and monitoring the console as you send the push.  If the push is received, then you should be able to see your device requesting the serials to be updated from your webservice and you should also see your server's response.

Assuming you send a serial and that it matches the serial installed on your device, you should then see the device requesting the updated .pkpass bundle.

If no push is received, try toggling automatic updates on and off while monitoring the device console.  It could be that the device is not receiving a valid registration (201) response or that you are using a stale token - you'll be able to see these via the console.